# Pull back of line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

The morphism $\phi : \mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^3:(u:v)\mapsto(u^4:u^3v:uv^3:v^4)$ gives an embedding of $\mathbb P^1$ in to $\mathbb P^3$.   What is  $\phi^*(  \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(1))? $.

Comment: This is $\mathcal O_{\Bbb P^1}(4)$.

Comment: @N.H.: Post as an answer...? :)

Comment: sure, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\phi^* \mathcal O_{\Bbb P^3}(D) \cong \mathcal O_{\Bbb P^1}(\phi^*D)$ for any divisor $D$ on $\Bbb P^3$ such that $\phi(\Bbb P^1) \not \subset D$, as MooS wrote in comments (else the pullback won't be a divisor). Notice that $\mathcal  O_{\Bbb P^3}(1) = \mathcal O_{\Bbb P^3}(H)$ where $H$ is an hyperplane, say $x_4 = 0$. Then $\phi^*H = 4 [\infty]$ and so $\phi^*O(1) \cong O_{\mathbb P^1}(4)$.

Comment: Your first isomorphism only holds, when $D$ does not contain the image of $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer.